# Keras metric does not provide same result as metric calculated in callback

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to do regression using a pretrained vgg16 network. As loss and also metric I have chosen the mean absolute error. I wanted to do a check if this score is actually correct and implemented the mean absolute score myself in a callback. However, the results are not the same as can be seen by the output:

```
Training MAE:126.649451276
Epoch 1/100
638/638 [==============================] - 406s - loss: 38.9601 - mean_absolute_error: 38.9601
Training MAE:40.7683742351

Epoch 2/100
638/638 [==============================] - 362s - loss: 19.8719 - mean_absolute_error: 19.8719
Training MAE:43.2516028945
```

The Training MAE should be the same (or at least almost the same), as the loss or the mean_absolute_error in the epoch above. For the first epoch this is ok. For the second epoch it is not. There the MAE is 43.24 but the loss is 19.87 and the mean_absolute_error provided by keras is 19.87.

I've cleaned up my code and tried to find a reason why but I can't find it. Why is this happening?

My code:

```
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import Model
import os
from keras.layers.core import *
from keras.callbacks import Callback, ModelCheckpoint

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"
model_checkpoints = "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/RSNA/model_checkpoints/model2.hdf5"
data_dir = "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/RSNA/data/"
data_training = "dataset/training"
training_images = "boneage-training-dataset/"
training_gt = "training_gt/"
n_batch = 16
n_training_samples = 10213
n_validation_samples = 1136
n_testing_samples = 1262

def mae(X,y,mdl):
    pred = mdl.predict(X)
    gt = y
    return str(np.mean(np.abs(np.array(gt)-np.array(pred))))

class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        mae_score = mae(X_train,y_train,self.model)
        print "Training MAE:" + mae_score


def regression_flow_from_directory(flow_from_directory_gen, rev_indices):
    for x, y in flow_from_directory_gen:
         yield x,  [float(rev_indices[val]) for val in y]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    width = 224
    height = 224
    X_train = []
    y_train = []

    train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range= 0.2,
    )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        data_dir+data_training,
        target_size=(width, height),
        batch_size=n_batch,
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='sparse',
        seed=42)


    indices = train_generator.class_indices
    rev_indices = dict((v,k) for k, v in indices.iteritems())

    train_generator = regression_flow_from_directory(train_generator,rev_indices)

    i = 0
    print "Epcohs: " + str(n_training_samples//n_batch)
    for x,y in train_generator:
        if i <= n_training_samples//n_batch:
            X_train.extend(x)
            y_train.extend(y)
            i +=1
        else:
            break;

    print "Maximum: " + str(np.max(y_train))

    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    print X_train.shape

    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_shape = (224, 224, 3))
    last = model.output
    x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5, noise_shape=None, seed=None)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='predictions')(x)

    my_model = Model(input=model.input, output=x)
    my_model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=0.00001, momentum=0.9),
                        metrics=["mae"])

    history = LossHistory()
    print my_model.summary()
    print n_validation_samples//n_batch
    my_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=n_training_samples//n_batch,
        epochs=100,
        callbacks=[history],
    )
```

Comment: Your implementation of mean absolute error is exactly the same as Keras'. But you seem to be calculating it on `X_train`, `y_train` while Keras calculates it on scaled and shifted versions (see train generator), hence the difference is all I can see. Can you try giving your loss function directly to `model.compile` with `loss(y_true, y_pred)` signature and see if it gives the same results with Keras mae metric?